# I want to download all images starting with "parkmu123.neocities.org/" and ending with ".jpg" or ".gif" from the crawled page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to crawl and download all the images I want, but the source code I wrote doesn't work. I am not very experienced with Python, so I would appreciate your help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import subprocess
import urllib.request
import time

res = requests.get("https://parkmu123.neocities.org/question")
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

search_string1 = "parkmu123.neocities.org/"
search_string2 = ".jpg"
search_string3 = ".gif"
img_dest = "c:/users/root/desktop/img/"

for i in soup:
    if (soup.startswitch(search_string1) and soup.endswitch(search_string2) or soup.startswitch(search_string1) and soup.endswitch(search_string3) ):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, img_dest+str(i+1)+".jpg or .gif")
    else:
        continue
```

I have succeeded in crawling web pages using "Beautifulsoup", but I am at a loss as to how to save all three image links on the homepage.

Comment: I don't know how `urlretrieve` works but most likely `+".jpg or .gif"` does not do what you hope it would do.

Comment: I didn't know how to edit that part, so I wrote it like that. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The image links are in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags. `for img in soup.find_all("img"): print(img.get("src"))`

Comment: The <img> tags does not exist on this site.

Comment: The source of the page is basically garbage. It's really not clear how you expect to do something useful with that page as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression

```
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(i, img_dest+str(i+1)+".jpg or .gif")
```

creates a file which ends with literally `".jpg or .gif"`. It's also not clear what you hope `str(i+1)` would do here; `i` is not a number.

Furthermore, in

```
for i in soup:
    if (soup.startswitch(search_string1) and soup.endswitch(search_string2) or soup.startswitch(search_string1) and soup.endswitch(search_string3) ):
```

you are repeatedly examining `soup`, and ignoring `i`. But furthermore, `for i in soup` will just loop over the top-level objects in the `soup` object (so basically the DOCTYPE declaration and the actual HTML tree).

Also, `findall` is not a valid method; where did you get that from? And you mistyped `startswith` and `endswith` (see what they mean? "Starts with" and "ends with"?)

Here is a version which extracts actual images, and removes a ton of unused imports.

```
import os
import urllib.request

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://parkmu123.neocities.org/question")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

search_string1 = "https://parkmu123.neocities.org/"  # notice https://
search_string2 = ".jpg"
search_string3 = ".gif"
img_dest = "c:/users/root/desktop/img/"

for i in soup.find_all("img"):
    img = i.get("src")
    if img.startswith(search_string1) and (img.endswith(search_string2) or img.endswith(search_string3)):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, os.path.join(img_dest, img.split("/")[-1]))
```

However, for the page you ask about, it does nothing; there are no valid image links, just garbage.

Also, mixing `requests` and `urllib` in the same script is slightly weird, but I wanted to focus on the obvious errors.

Answer (score -1):

Look into regular expressions, or regex. BeautifulSoup can work with that module which can easily find the files you're looking for. I don't know enough about BeautifulSoup to give you a code that works, but an expression like `parkmu123\.neocities\.org/.+\.(jpg|gif)` should find all the files you want.